# Add constraint on view

Tags: swift, uiview

I would like to know how can I fix the height of a view so it can take full height of the device screen (iPhone only) minus the height of the tabar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I would click the UIView in question then towards the bottom right there is an icon looks like |o|  (kind of)....its the pin menu

tap that

and make sure the top and bottom are solid orange...not the faded semi dotted orange and then put 0 in each of them

what do you mean by "tabar" ...are you referring to the status bar where the time and wifi signal are etc?

**Response to comment**

if you add the navigation bar first, then add the view and physically drag the bounds to the top left top right bottom left and bottom right and then do what i said it should have desired effect

Comment: By tab bar I mean the navigation bar, like Facebook or instagram use to navigate between view controllers

Comment: it seems like the button is disable

Comment: you have to have the view you want selected...the view can be a UIView or a UIImage etc etc...but you have to have something selected

Comment: no problem, please mark correct if my answer helped :)

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let rect : CGRect = (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)!
        let y = rect.size.height + rect.origin.y
        self.view.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(y, 0, 0, 0)
    }
```

This is the best example I can provide, since you didn't specify much. This adjusts the bounds of view if the view controller has a navigation bar

Comment: By tab bar I mean the navigation bar, like Facebook or instagram use to navigate between view controllers

Comment: Yeah, I assumed you meant navigation bar, see the code.

Comment: I got an error, 'value of type "My view controller name" has no member view

Comment: Can you tell me what your class is like? Is it a UIViewController? Is it a UITableViewController?

Comment: unless you have a need to do it programmatically i would recommend doing it the visual way

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 The problem with that is you would have to add a new view to your view controller. Why not use the already built in view and save some resource (more efficient)

Comment: @AkshanshThakur only reason I would personally is because some people are visual and it helps to see what your app will look like...and its just easier in general...you are right and it probably is less efficient but i would imagine it is minimal on such powerful devices these days :)

Comment: The class is UIViewController, the vies's class I'm trying to set up is DesignableView (Spring framework)

Answer (score 1):

You can also apply layout constraints (auto resizing) which are in the inspector menu.
Apply all 4 side constraints to make your view always full size for all the devices.
[image: auto resizing image.]